# Kafka issue with adding SASL security

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, confluent-platform, sasl

I'm using Confluent Community 6.0.1. Three nodes Kafka cluster:

devKafka04: Kafka Broker1, Zookeeper 1

devKafka05: Kafka Broker2, Zookeeper 2

devKafka06: Kafka Broker3, Zookeeper 3

The SSL encryption is already working well on the Kafka Brokers.

I'd like to add SASL to enable mutual authentication between Kafka and Zookeeper.
I was following the Confluent document:
https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka/incremental-security-upgrade.html#adding-security-to-a-running-zk-cluster

[Updates] After I applied the changes, Zookeeper could not start on the secureclientPort. That's why the Kafka broker couldn't start. Here are the error log and docker compose configurations.

I'm wondering if there's something with the confluent zookeeper image.

Please help me out. Thanks.

$ sudo docker logs zookeeper

```
===> User
uid=1000(appuser) gid=1000(appuser) groups=1000(appuser)
===> Configuring ...
===> Running preflight checks ...
===> Check if /var/lib/zookeeper/data is writable ...
===> Check if /var/lib/zookeeper/log is writable ...
===> Launching ...
===> Printing /var/lib/zookeeper/data/myid
1===> Launching zookeeper ...
[2021-03-24 19:03:08,857] INFO Reading configuration from: /etc/kafka/zookeeper.properties (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig)
[2021-03-24 19:03:08,862] INFO clientPortAddress is 0.0.0.0:2181 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig)
[2021-03-24 19:03:08,862] INFO secureClientPort is not set (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig)
[2021-03-24 19:03:08,876] INFO autopurge.snapRetainCount set to 3 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.DatadirCleanupManager)
[2021-03-24 19:03:08,876] INFO autopurge.purgeInterval set to 0 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.DatadirCleanupManager)
[2021-03-24 19:03:08,876] INFO Purge task is not scheduled. (org.apache.zookeeper.server.DatadirCleanupManager)
[2021-03-24 19:03:08,880] INFO Log4j 1.2 jmx support found and enabled. (org.apache.zookeeper.jmx.ManagedUtil)
[2021-03-24 19:03:08,904] INFO Starting quorum peer (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain)
[2021-03-24 19:03:08,909] INFO Using org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory as server connection factory (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ServerCnxnFactory)
[2021-03-24 19:03:08,917] INFO Setting -D jdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation=true to disable client-initiated TLS renegotiation (org.apache.zookeeper.common.X509Util)
[2021-03-24 19:03:08,953] INFO Server successfully logged in. (org.apache.zookeeper.Login)
[2021-03-24 19:03:08,957] INFO Configuring NIO connection handler with 10s sessionless connection timeout, 1 selector thread(s), 8 worker threads, and 64 kB direct buffers. (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory)
[2021-03-24 19:03:08,961] INFO binding to port 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory)
[2021-03-24 19:03:08,986] INFO Logging initialized @929ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog (org.eclipse.jetty.util.log)
[2021-03-24 19:03:09,081] WARN o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@6c2c1385{/,null,UNAVAILABLE} contextPath ends with /* (org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler)
[2021-03-24 19:03:09,082] WARN Empty contextPath (org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler)
[2021-03-24 19:03:09,097] INFO zookeeper.snapshot.trust.empty : false (org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnSnapLog)
[2021-03-24 19:03:09,102] INFO Local sessions disabled (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer)
[2021-03-24 19:03:09,102] INFO Local session upgrading disabled (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer)
[2021-03-24 19:03:09,102] INFO tickTime set to 3000 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer)
[2021-03-24 19:03:09,102] INFO minSessionTimeout set to 6000 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer)
[2021-03-24 19:03:09,102] INFO maxSessionTimeout set to 60000 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer)
[2021-03-24 19:03:09,102] INFO initLimit set to 10 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer)
[2021-03-24 19:03:09,115] INFO zookeeper.snapshotSizeFactor = 0.33 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZKDatabase)
[2021-03-24 19:03:09,116] INFO Using insecure (non-TLS) quorum communication (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer)
[2021-03-24 19:03:09,117] INFO Port unification disabled (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer)
[2021-03-24 19:03:09,117] INFO QuorumPeer communication is not secured! (SASL auth disabled) (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer)
[2021-03-24 19:03:09,117] INFO quorum.cnxn.threads.size set to 20 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer)
[2021-03-24 19:03:09,118] INFO Reading snapshot /var/lib/zookeeper/data/version-2/snapshot.a00000000 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileSnap)
[2021-03-24 19:03:09,213] INFO jetty-9.4.24.v20191120; built: 2019-11-20T21:37:49.771Z; git: 363d5f2df3a8a28de40604320230664b9c793c16; jvm 11.0.9.1+1-LTS (org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server)
[2021-03-24 19:03:09,261] INFO DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0 (org.eclipse.jetty.server.session)
[2021-03-24 19:03:09,261] INFO No SessionScavenger set, using defaults (org.eclipse.jetty.server.session)
[2021-03-24 19:03:09,263] INFO node0 Scavenging every 660000ms (org.eclipse.jetty.server.session)
[2021-03-24 19:03:09,272] INFO Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@6c2c1385{/,null,AVAILABLE} (org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler)
[2021-03-24 19:03:09,281] INFO Started ServerConnector@6d07a63d{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080} (org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector)
[2021-03-24 19:03:09,281] INFO Started @1224ms (org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server)
[2021-03-24 19:03:09,281] INFO Started AdminServer on address 0.0.0.0, port 8080 and command URL /commands (org.apache.zookeeper.server.admin.JettyAdminServer)
[2021-03-24 19:03:09,288] INFO Election port bind maximum retries is 3 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager)
[2021-03-24 19:03:09,290] INFO 1 is accepting connections now, my election bind port: devkafka04/172.16.87.141:3888 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager)
[2021-03-24 19:03:09,301] INFO LOOKING (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer)
[2021-03-24 19:03:09,303] INFO New election. My id =  1, proposed zxid=0x1600000030 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.FastLeaderElection)
[2021-03-24 19:03:09,308] INFO Notification: 2 (message format version), 1 (n.leader), 0x1600000030 (n.zxid), 0x1 (n.round), LOOKING (n.state), 1 (n.sid), 0x16 (n.peerEPoch), LOOKING (my state)0 (n.config version) (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.FastLeaderElection)
[2021-03-24 19:03:09,310] INFO Have smaller server identifier, so dropping the connection: (myId:1 --> sid:3) (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager)
[2021-03-24 19:03:09,312] INFO Received connection request from /172.16.87.143:53340 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager)
[2021-03-24 19:03:09,315] INFO Have smaller server identifier, so dropping the connection: (myId:1 --> sid:2) (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager)
[2021-03-24 19:03:09,316] INFO Notification: 2 (message format version), 2 (n.leader), 0x150000002b (n.zxid), 0xa (n.round), FOLLOWING (n.state), 3 (n.sid), 0x16 (n.peerEPoch), LOOKING (my state)0 (n.config version) (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.FastLeaderElection)
[2021-03-24 19:03:09,317] INFO Received connection request from /172.16.87.142:51704 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager)
[2021-03-24 19:03:09,319] INFO Notification: 2 (message format version), 2 (n.leader), 0x150000002b (n.zxid), 0xa (n.round), LEADING (n.state), 2 (n.sid), 0x16 (n.peerEPoch), LOOKING (my state)0 (n.config version) (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.FastLeaderElection)
[2021-03-24 19:03:09,320] INFO Notification: 2 (message format version), 2 (n.leader), 0x150000002b (n.zxid), 0xa (n.round), FOLLOWING (n.state), 3 (n.sid), 0x16 (n.peerEPoch), LOOKING (my state)0 (n.config version) (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.FastLeaderElection)
[2021-03-24 19:03:09,320] INFO FOLLOWING (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer)
[2021-03-24 19:03:09,323] INFO Notification: 2 (message format version), 2 (n.leader), 0x150000002b (n.zxid), 0xa (n.round), LEADING (n.state), 2 (n.sid), 0x16 (n.peerEPoch), FOLLOWING (my state)0 (n.config version) (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.FastLeaderElection)
[2021-03-24 19:03:09,330] INFO TCP NoDelay set to: true (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.Learner)
[2021-03-24 19:03:09,336] INFO Server environment:zookeeper.version=3.5.8-f439ca583e70862c3068a1f2a7d4d068eec33315, built on 05/04/2020 15:53 GMT (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2021-03-24 19:03:09,336] INFO Server environment:host.name=devkafka04 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2021-03-24 19:03:09,336] INFO Server environment:java.version=11.0.9.1 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2021-03-24 19:03:09,336] INFO Server environment:java.vendor=Azul Systems, Inc. (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2021-03-24 19:03:09,336] INFO Server environment:java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/zulu11-ca (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2021-03-24 19:03:09,336] INFO Server environment:java.class.path=/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/activation-1.1.1.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/aopalliance-repackaged-2.6.1.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/argparse4j-0.7.0.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/audience-annotations-0.5.0.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/commons-cli-1.4.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/confluent-log4j-1.2.17-cp2.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/connect-api-6.0.1-ccs.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/connect-basic-auth-extension-6.0.1-ccs.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/connect-file-6.0.1-ccs.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/connect-json-6.0.1-ccs.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/connect-mirror-6.0.1-ccs.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/connect-mirror-client-6.0.1-ccs.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/connect-runtime-6.0.1-ccs.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/connect-transforms-6.0.1-ccs.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/hk2-api-2.6.1.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/hk2-locator-2.6.1.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/hk2-utils-2.6.1.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/jackson-annotations-2.10.5.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/jackson-core-2.10.5.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/jackson-databind-2.10.5.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/jackson-dataformat-csv-2.10.5.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.10.5.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/jackson-jaxrs-base-2.10.5.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.10.5.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.10.5.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/jackson-module-paranamer-2.10.5.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/jackson-module-scala_2.13-2.10.5.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/jakarta.inject-2.6.1.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/jakarta.validation-api-2.0.2.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/jakarta.ws.rs-api-2.1.6.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/javassist-3.25.0-GA.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/javassist-3.26.0-GA.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/javax.ws.rs-api-2.1.1.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/jersey-client-2.30.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/jersey-common-2.30.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/jersey-container-servlet-2.30.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/jersey-container-servlet-core-2.30.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/jersey-hk2-2.30.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/jersey-media-jaxb-2.30.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/jersey-server-2.30.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/jetty-client-9.4.24.v20191120.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/jetty-continuation-9.4.24.v20191120.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/jetty-http-9.4.24.v20191120.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/jetty-io-9.4.24.v20191120.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/jetty-security-9.4.24.v20191120.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/jetty-server-9.4.24.v20191120.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/jetty-servlet-9.4.24.v20191120.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/jetty-servlets-9.4.24.v20191120.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/jetty-util-9.4.24.v20191120.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/jopt-simple-5.0.4.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/kafka-clients-6.0.1-ccs.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/kafka-log4j-appender-6.0.1-ccs.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/kafka-streams-6.0.1-ccs.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/kafka-streams-examples-6.0.1-ccs.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/kafka-streams-scala_2.13-6.0.1-ccs.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/kafka-streams-test-utils-6.0.1-ccs.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/kafka-tools-6.0.1-ccs.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/kafka.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/kafka_2.13-6.0.1-ccs-javadoc.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/kafka_2.13-6.0.1-ccs-scaladoc.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/kafka_2.13-6.0.1-ccs-sources.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/kafka_2.13-6.0.1-ccs-test-sources.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/kafka_2.13-6.0.1-ccs-test.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/kafka_2.13-6.0.1-ccs.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/lz4-java-1.7.1.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/maven-artifact-3.6.3.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/metrics-core-2.2.0.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/netty-buffer-4.1.50.Final.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/netty-codec-4.1.50.Final.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/netty-common-4.1.50.Final.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/netty-handler-4.1.50.Final.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/netty-resolver-4.1.50.Final.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.50.Final.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/netty-transport-native-unix-common-4.1.50.Final.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/osgi-resource-locator-1.0.3.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/paranamer-2.8.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/plexus-utils-3.2.1.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/reflections-0.9.12.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/rocksdbjni-5.18.4.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/scala-collection-compat_2.13-2.1.6.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/scala-java8-compat_2.13-0.9.1.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/scala-library-2.13.2.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/slf4j-api-1.7.30.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/scala-logging_2.13-3.9.2.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/scala-reflect-2.13.2.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.30.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/snappy-java-1.1.7.3.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/zookeeper-3.5.8.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/zookeeper-jute-3.5.8.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/zstd-jni-1.4.4-7.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/confluent-telemetry/* (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2021-03-24 19:03:09,336] INFO Server environment:java.library.path=/usr/java/packages/lib:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2021-03-24 19:03:09,336] INFO Server environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2021-03-24 19:03:09,336] INFO Server environment:java.compiler=<NA> (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2021-03-24 19:03:09,337] INFO Server environment:os.name=Linux (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2021-03-24 19:03:09,337] INFO Server environment:os.arch=amd64 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2021-03-24 19:03:09,337] INFO Server environment:os.version=3.10.0-1160.21.1.el7.x86_64 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2021-03-24 19:03:09,337] INFO Server environment:user.name=appuser (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2021-03-24 19:03:09,337] INFO Server environment:user.home=/home/appuser (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2021-03-24 19:03:09,337] INFO Server environment:user.dir=/home/appuser (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2021-03-24 19:03:09,337] INFO Server environment:os.memory.free=498MB (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2021-03-24 19:03:09,337] INFO Server environment:os.memory.max=512MB (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2021-03-24 19:03:09,337] INFO Server environment:os.memory.total=512MB (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2021-03-24 19:03:09,338] INFO minSessionTimeout set to 6000 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2021-03-24 19:03:09,339] INFO maxSessionTimeout set to 60000 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2021-03-24 19:03:09,339] INFO Created server with tickTime 3000 minSessionTimeout 6000 maxSessionTimeout 60000 datadir /var/lib/zookeeper/log/version-2 snapdir /var/lib/zookeeper/data/version-2 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2021-03-24 19:03:09,339] INFO FOLLOWING - LEADER ELECTION TOOK - 18 MS (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.Learner)
[2021-03-24 19:03:09,345] INFO Getting a diff from the leader 0x1600000030 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.Learner)
[2021-03-24 19:03:09,350] INFO Learner received NEWLEADER message (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.Learner)
[2021-03-24 19:03:09,363] INFO Learner received UPTODATE message (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.Learner)
[2021-03-24 19:03:09,367] INFO Configuring CommitProcessor with 4 worker threads. (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.CommitProcessor)
```

$ sudo docker logs kafka

```
===> User
uid=1000(appuser) gid=1000(appuser) groups=1000(appuser)
===> Configuring ...
SSL is enabled.
SASL is enabled.
===> Running preflight checks ...
===> Check if /var/lib/kafka/data is writable ...
===> Skipping Zookeeper health check for SSL connections...
===> Launching ...
===> Launching kafka ...
[2021-03-23 21:43:43,453] INFO Registered kafka:type=kafka.Log4jController MBean (kafka.utils.Log4jControllerRegistration$)
[2021-03-23 21:43:43,838] INFO Setting -D jdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation=true to disable client-initiated TLS renegotiation (org.apache.zookeeper.common.X509Util)
[2021-03-23 21:43:43,900] INFO Registered signal handlers for TERM, INT, HUP (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.LoggingSignalHandler)
[2021-03-23 21:43:43,904] INFO starting (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2021-03-23 21:43:43,905] INFO Connecting to zookeeper on devkafka04:2182,devkafka05:2182,devkafka06:2182 (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2021-03-23 21:43:43,927] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Initializing a new session to devkafka04:2182,devkafka05:2182,devkafka06:2182. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2021-03-23 21:43:43,934] INFO Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.5.8-f439ca583e70862c3068a1f2a7d4d068eec33315, built on 05/04/2020 15:53 GMT (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2021-03-23 21:43:43,934] INFO Client environment:host.name=devkafka04 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2021-03-23 21:43:43,934] INFO Client environment:java.version=11.0.9.1 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2021-03-23 21:43:43,934] INFO Client environment:java.vendor=Azul Systems, Inc. (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
------ Repeating lines removed ---------
'Client' (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2021-03-23 21:43:59,947] INFO Socket error occurred: devkafka05/172.16.87.142:2182: Connection refused (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2021-03-23 21:44:01,048] INFO Client successfully logged in. (org.apache.zookeeper.Login)
[2021-03-23 21:44:01,048] INFO Client will use DIGEST-MD5 as SASL mechanism. (org.apache.zookeeper.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient)
[2021-03-23 21:44:01,048] INFO Opening socket connection to server devkafka04/172.16.87.141:2182. Will attempt to SASL-authenticate using Login Context section 'Client' (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2021-03-23 21:44:01,049] INFO Socket error occurred: devkafka04/172.16.87.141:2182: Connection refused (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2021-03-23 21:44:01,150] INFO Client successfully logged in. (org.apache.zookeeper.Login)
[2021-03-23 21:44:01,150] INFO Client will use DIGEST-MD5 as SASL mechanism. (org.apache.zookeeper.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient)
[2021-03-23 21:44:01,150] INFO Opening socket connection to server devkafka06/172.16.87.143:2182. Will attempt to SASL-authenticate using Login Context section 'Client' (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2021-03-23 21:44:01,153] INFO Socket error occurred: devkafka06/172.16.87.143:2182: Connection refused (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2021-03-23 21:44:01,254] INFO Client successfully logged in. (org.apache.zookeeper.Login)
[2021-03-23 21:44:01,254] INFO Client will use DIGEST-MD5 as SASL mechanism. (org.apache.zookeeper.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient)
[2021-03-23 21:44:01,254] INFO Opening socket connection to server devkafka05/172.16.87.142:2182. Will attempt to SASL-authenticate using Login Context section 'Client' (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2021-03-23 21:44:01,255] INFO Socket error occurred: devkafka05/172.16.87.142:2182: Connection refused (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2021-03-23 21:44:01,952] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Closing. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2021-03-23 21:44:02,356] INFO Client successfully logged in. (org.apache.zookeeper.Login)
[2021-03-23 21:44:02,357] INFO Client will use DIGEST-MD5 as SASL mechanism. (org.apache.zookeeper.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient)
[2021-03-23 21:44:02,357] INFO Opening socket connection to server devkafka04/172.16.87.141:2182. Will attempt to SASL-authenticate using Login Context section 'Client' (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2021-03-23 21:44:02,462] INFO Session: 0x0 closed (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2021-03-23 21:44:02,463] INFO EventThread shut down for session: 0x0 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2021-03-23 21:44:02,465] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Closed. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2021-03-23 21:44:02,469] ERROR Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClientTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for connection while in state: CONNECTING
        at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.waitUntilConnected(ZooKeeperClient.scala:262)
        at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.<init>(ZooKeeperClient.scala:119)
        at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient$.apply(KafkaZkClient.scala:1865)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.createZkClient$1(KafkaServer.scala:419)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.initZkClient(KafkaServer.scala:444)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:222)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:44)
        at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:82)
        at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
[2021-03-23 21:44:02,471] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2021-03-23 21:44:02,478] INFO shut down completed (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2021-03-23 21:44:02,478] ERROR Exiting Kafka. (kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable)
[2021-03-23 21:44:02,479] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
```

$ sudo cat kafka-docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services: 
  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.0.1
    container_name: kafka
    network_mode: host
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9093:9093"
      - "9094:9094"
      - "49998:49998"
      - "49999:49999"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'devkafka04:2182,devkafka05:2182,devkafka06:2182'
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_SSL_CLIENT_ENABLE: 'true'
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CLIENTCNXNSOCKET: org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNetty
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_FILENAME: kafka.server.truststore.jks
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_CREDENTIALS: creds
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_SET_ACL: 'true'
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://devkafka04:9092,SSL://devkafka04:9093,SASL_SSL://devkafka04:9094
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://devkafka04:9092,SSL://devkafka04:9093,SASL_SSL://devkafka04:9094
      KAFKA_SASL_ENABLED_MECHANISMS: DIGEST-MD5
      KAFKA_SECURITY_INTER_BROKER_PROTOCOL: SSL
      KAFKA_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH: requested
      KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_FILENAME: kafka.server.truststore.jks
      KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_CREDENTIALS: creds
      KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_FILENAME: devkafka04.server.keystore.jks
      KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_CREDENTIALS: creds
      KAFKA_SSL_KEY_CREDENTIALS: creds
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 3
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: "false"
      KAFKA_OPTS: -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/kafka/jmx/kafka_server_jaas.conf -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=devkafka04 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=49998 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=49998 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -javaagent:/etc/kafka/jmx/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.14.0.jar=49999:/etc/kafka/jmx/kafka-2_0_0.yml
      CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_METRICS_ENABLE: "false"
    volumes:
      -  /media/kafka/data:/var/lib/kafka/data
      -  /media/kafka/secrets:/etc/kafka/secrets
      -  /usr/local/src/kafka/jmx:/etc/kafka/jmx
```

$ sudo cat jmx/kafka_server_jaas.conf

```
KafkaServer {
   org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
   username="kafkabroker"
   password="kafkabroker-secret"
   user_kafkabroker="kafkabroker-secret"
   user_kafka-broker-metric-reporter="kafkabroker-metric-reporter-secret"
   user_client="client-secret";
};

Client {
   org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.DigestLoginModule required
   username="kafka"
   password="kafka-secret";
};
```

$ sudo cat zookeeper-docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:6.0.1
    container_name: zookeeper
    network_mode: host
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
      - "2182:2182"
      - "2888:2888"
      - "3888:3888"
      - "39998:39998"
      - "39999:39999"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 1
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: devkafka04:2888:3888;devkafka05:2888:3888;devkafka06:2888:3888
      ZOOKEEPER_AUTHPROVIDER_SASL: org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.SASLAuthenticationProvider
      ZOOKEEPER_AUTHPROVIDER_x509: org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.X509AuthenticationProvider
      ZOOKEEPER_SECURECLIENTPORT: 2182
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVERCNXNFACTORY: org.apache.zookeeper.server.NettyServerCnxnFactory
      ZOOKEEPER_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_FILENAME: kafka.server.truststore.jks
      ZOOKEEPER_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_CREDENTIALS: creds
      ZOOKEEPER_SSL_KEYSTORE_FILENAME: devkafka05.server.keystore.jks
      ZOOKEEPER_SSL_KEYSTORE_CREDENTIALS: creds
      ZOOKEEPER_SSL_KEY_CREDENTIALS: creds
      ZOOKEEPER_SSL_CLIENTAUTH: none
      KAFKA_OPTS: -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/zookeeper/jmx/zookeeper_jaas.conf -Dzookeeper.4lw.commands.whitelist=* -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=devkafka04 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=39998 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=39998 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -javaagent:/etc/zookeeper/jmx/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.14.0.jar=39999:/etc/zookeeper/jmx/jmx-zookeeper-prometheus.yaml
    volumes:
      -  /media/zookeeper/data:/var/lib/zookeeper/data
      -  /media/zookeeper/log:/var/lib/zookeeper/log
      -  /media/zookeeper/secrets:/etc/zookeeper/secrets
      -  /usr/local/src/zookeeper/jmx:/etc/zookeeper/jmx
```

$ sudo cat jmx/zookeeper_jaas.conf

```
Server {
       org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.DigestLoginModule required
       user_kafka="kafka-secret";
};
```

Comment: You should put your Zookeeper and Kafka services in the same compose file... Unless they're on separate servers, in which case, you should probably just use Confluent Helm Charts, or other kubernetes solution

Comment: Thanks for your answer @OneCricketeer. I don't see any difference in the separation of compose file. And it's been working well for a year.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_CNXN_SOCKET` instead of `KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CLIENTCNXNSOCKET`.